# what is the alternative method to list.find() in wp7

Tags: list, windows-phone-7, generic-list, generic-collections

I have a List<> of objects. I wanted to use the method Find(Predicate match), but i did not find it in wp7.

What can i use in alternative to this method?

thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq instead. The equivalent of `Find` in Linq is `FirstOrDefault`:

```
yourList.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
```

Just make sure you have added `using System.Linq;` on top of your file, or you won't find the `FirstOrDefault` method.

Comment: i used 'list.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();'